# Geoserver WFS Cross Layer Filtering and String IDs

Tags: cql, geoserver

I have a Geoserver WFS request with a cross layer filter based cql in it, that looks like this:

```
...&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS(the_geom, querySingle('myLayerName','the_geom','the_id = F338'))
```

This does not work. Geoserver is giving me this error message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: PropertyDescriptor is null - did you
>   request a property that does not exist?

if I change the filter to this:

```
&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS(the_geom, querySingle('myLayerName','the_geom','INCLUDE'))
```

it is working.

What could be going wrong in the first example? The id with the value F338 in fact does exist.

Could it be that Geoserver is expecting a integer as id? In CQL filters can be strings, but they have to be quoted. In my example, i obviously cannot really quote the value because the whole parameter to the `querySingle` function is a quote itself.

Comment: What happens if you use '"the_id"="F338"' as the filter? also is the_id the fid? if so you might want to use 'IN (F338)'

Comment: It works when `the_id` is of a `number` type. Your first guess does not work either. How can i set a `fid` on the layer to try out your second guess? Thx

Answer (score 3):

For string comparison, you need to put two single quotations, so i.e. 
'the_id = ''F338'''. (one double quotation doesn't work)

This stupid undocumented little thing cost me 5 hours of try and error...

Comment: Looks kinda weird. I will try this out.